# SQL statement causing deadlock because multiple resource are handling the query

Tags: sql

This SQL statement is causing a deadlock because multiple resources are handling these query. Is there a way to avoid the deadlock?

```
DELETE
  (SELECT COD_INCOLOANID_123, COD_INCOID_123
   FROM HSBC_ICL_LOAN_DTLS_123
   INNER JOIN OLM_INCO_LOAN_DETAILS_123 USING (COD_INCOLOANID_123,COD_INCOID_123)
   WHERE OLM_INCO_LOAN_DETAILS.COD_DOMICILEGL = 'ABCD'
  )
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Probably a product specific problem.)

Comment: did u try using transactions?

Comment: what do u mean by transaction?

Comment: 3 options: remove the outer paranthesis; rewrite using only DELETE xxx WHERE yyy; with T-SQL it's FROM HSBC_ICL_LOAN_DTLS_123(WITH NOLOCK)